# Extending linearLayout having multiple states (different controls) defined in XML

Tags: layout, custom-controls

I do have a custom layout with some controls written in an XML layout file.
a class is attached to this layout like

```
<com.project.layout ...>
  <Checkbox...1
  <TextView...2
  <Button ...3
  <ImageView..4 ...
../>
```

depending on the user interaction i would like to display only 3 of the defined controls like 1,2,3. With a click from the user i'd like to have 1,2,4
To do so, i developed some state classes that handle the removeView and addView.

I have some issues about this as:
1/ When can i be sure everything is created and i can interact with the UI (onLayout() & onMeasure() seem to happen everytime a control is processed)
2/ it seems that since i defined the layout with the 4 controls, even thought i write removeView, the space used by the removed control is not used by the other controls... is there a way i can ask the layout to reorder it display?

Answer (score 0):

[I found out , it turns out it was easy](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html) actually, there is a method i have to override called `onFinishInflate()`.